# AWS API Gateway , Returning "null" in response

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

Before I asked question, I tried to find solution by google but didn't get answer so writing here

[I’ve followed all steps that describe in this link.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html#how-to-generate-sdk-ios)

But I am getting **(null)** response after all call using

```
AWSTask *task = [serviceClient myAPI : “Parameter”];
```

But when I tried invoke **URL** in postman with its - `AccessKey, SecretKey, AWS Region, Service Name - parameters`,  I am getting proper response.

**(My api key is disabled)**

**EDITED:**

When i’ve used below code then I was getting ***(null)*** response.

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1  identityPoolId:@"YourIdentityPoolId"];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSWest2 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

But when using below code then got ***Blank/Nothing*** response.

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:@“KEY” secretKey:@“KEY”];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSWest2  credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Anybody will help me to solve my issue?

Comment: For Parameters where are you strong the AWS credentials?

Comment: @error2007s - Thanks for your quick response. Please check my edited post, so might be you will get an idea.

Comment: Maybe another code example here would help? This is a full example of an integration with Cognito. I think the Podfile is out of date, but the code should be a good eample. See other files in that package. https://github.com/awslabs/api-gateway-secure-pet-store/blob/master/src/main/resources/ios_sample/PetTest/LoginViewController.m